# angular2: Obserable<Response> subscribeOnCompleted is not defined

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Im trying to execute a request in angular 2. 
I have few subscribes to that http request and I want do be able to do a function after all subscribes are done..

According ot rxjs documentation `subscribeOnCompleted` is the function I want but for some reason I get method undefined..
anyone have idea why?

This is the Code:

```
class MyHttp extends SomeExternalLibClassThatExtendHttp {
 request(url....) {
  ...
  ...
  return super.request(..)
    .subscribeOnCompleted(res => res.json); <-- this need's to be last
 }
}
```

The external lib also have some subscribes to the request.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, subscribeOnCompleted has been removed from RxJS 5. You need to use the regular subscribe function and pass your callback as the third parameter.

By the way, the RxJS 5 docs are here: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/

Answer (score -1):

I use toPromise() of Observerable and than call Kriskowal's Q.all(Promise[])

Also third callback in subscribe method is a complete callback. There you could increment a counter which would be accessible in all complete callbacks. When counter reaches the limit of tasks execute you custom method.

Comment: This wont work since I dont know how much subscribes there is to the external lib..

Comment: im using an external lib called 'ng2-ui-auth` and im extending the `JwtHttp` class.. So when I do `return super.request...` it calls the request of the `JwtHttp`. There he expected to get the response at it is.. thats why I cannot just use `.map` on the request https://github.com/ronzeidman/ng2-ui-auth

Comment: ok, but typings says 
request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response>;
which means you get Observable<Response>. you should be able to subscribe to it. subscribe's third param is onComplete.

I'm not sure if I miss something but if you have multiple subscribers and want to do something after all of them finish you could use Observable.forkJoin

Comment: I think i looked in the wrong place at the documentation.. http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html this is the right place and there is no `subscribeOnCompleted` method